# gnome failure after installing Ubuntu, prompted to command-line

Tags: boot, command-line, gnome

So I tried to install Ubuntu in several ways (vm, dual boot, usb) but every time after using the os for a few hours an error pops up and slowly I can't launch any graphical software and prompted to the command-line at the next boot

I tried running xserver and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and lightdm, nothing helped

Comment: You wrote "an error pops up" -- what exactly is the error message?

Comment: The error message was before the reboot and it said that the program couldn't find some updates

Comment: hey @Elias forgot to dm you